# Android + Hilt: Dependency cycle injecting a repo into a service which is going to be used by an activity

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have a Service (which is going to be used in an activity) that needs a Repository to be injected in it. I tried providing it with constructor injection (the preferred way), but I was not able to do it like this because I also need a module with a @Provides for the Service itself, who is going to be used in an activity through field injection (because as far as I know I cannot use constructor injection in Activities), and if I do constructor injection for the repo then, when I need to create the @Provides for the service:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideMyService(): MyService {
    return MyService()
}
```

It complains about missing constructor parameters for MyService and, if I do:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideMyService(myService: MyService): MyService {
    return myService
}
```

It complains about a "Dependency cycle".

In resume, my activity uses a service (located in one module of my app) and the service needs the repo (located in another module), and I need to find the correct dependency injection way for the whole "chain" to work.

For now, activity gets Service injected -through field injection- > Service gets Repository injected -through an EntryPoint-

One of the. things I tried is a module with the next piece of code:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideTrackRepository(trackRepository: TrackRepository): TrackRepository {
    return trackRepository
}

@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface TrackRepositoryInterface {
    fun getTrackRepository(): TrackRepository
}
```

And when building I get the following message:

> /myApp/app/build/generated/hilt/component_sources/debug/com/myApp/myApp/app/AWApplication_HiltComponents.java:141:
> error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:   public
> abstract static class SingletonC implements
> com.myApp.repository.local.Dependencies.TrackRepositoryInterface,
> ^
> com.myApp.repository.local.TrackRepository is injected at
> com.myApp.repository.local.Dependencies.provideTrackRepository(trackRepository)
> com.myApp.repository.local.TrackRepository is injected at
> com.myApp.repository.local.Dependencies.provideTrackRepository(trackRepository)
> The cycle is requested via:
> com.myApp.repository.local.TrackRepository is requested at
> com.myApp.repository.local.Dependencies.TrackRepositoryInterface.getTrackRepository()

But if I do:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideTrackRepository(): TrackRepository {
    return TrackRepository()
}

@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface TrackRepositoryInterface {
    fun getTrackRepository(): TrackRepository
}
```

It builds and works correctly, but I'm not sure if this second way is a correct way for "dependency injection class providing" or not.

Some people is redirecting me to

https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes

But I've read this "poor" and "not very clear" -in my opinion- documentation several times, and I'm still stuck.

They're trying to sell Hilt as a very easy dependency injection library, but IMHO working on a multi-module app with Hilt is a true nightmare.

Comment: "It complains about missing constructor parameters for MyService" -- what are the constructor parameters?

Comment: If I use constructor injection, the constructor injected fields became the main constructor parameters (if I'm not wrong).

Comment: "They're trying to sell Hilt as a very easy dependency injection library, but IMHO working on a multi-module app with Hilt is a true nightmare." because you don't understand how it works and how you should use it. Have you read https://dagger.dev/hilt/?

Comment: also there is samples and codelabes you can take https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#additional-resources

Comment: I'll read it @IR42, take it for sure, and thanks for your contribution :)